# How to add web interface to c++ project

Tags: c++, web, corba

I have an application built on C++ code and deployed on UNIX machine. I have one VB front end interface for this code which is communicating using CORBA (ORBIX).

Now I need to add new web interface to this existing application. How can I do this without changing much of the existing application and code.

Comment: How about this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pion/

Comment: See R2CORBA (http://osportal.remedy.nl/projects/r2corba) for a CORBA implementation for Ruby, that makes it pretty easy to use CORBA from a Ruby on Rails application